# How to open a pdf on same page using pdf.js

Tags: html, pdf

I want to open up a pdf page on a web page on click of an icon and I want that page to be opened on the same page. I tried to use - pdf.js, but I am facing problem in running helloworld of pdf.js. So how do I use odf.js locally?

Link referred: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported all the necessary scripts in `src` and put them in the right location (at `../..`)?

Comment: i have just downloaded the zip and trying to run - "helloworld" example. That itself is not working for me!

Comment: @SurjithSM she wants it embedded. Please read before commenting :P

Comment: @Smitha what browser? I downloaded the zip and opened "helloworld/index.html" and it works.

Comment: @SurjithSM "opened on the same page". Also that's the whole point of the library, did you check it out?

Comment: i have tried opening index.html on chrome and mozilla. It just shows me a canvas.

Comment: interesting. It does that for me on IE.

Comment: So what's the solution? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: it does not work with file://, you need to upload the files to your webserver, because AJAX just works with a webserver and not on the clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the issue you are experiencing but you will want to turn off web workers if you're using PDF.JS in multiple instances on the same page.

PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

Answer (score 0):

it does not work with file://, you need to upload the files to your webserver, because AJAX just works with a webserver and not on the clientside